# Python : Change datatype of hdf5 array

Tags: python, hdf5

I have hdf5 array as bellow:

```
>>> a = np.array([5,8])
>>> f = h5py.File('try.hdf5')
>>> f['try'] = a
>>> f['try']
<HDF5 dataset "try": shape (2,), type "<i4">
```

I want to change datatype of `f['try']` to `float64`. How to do it?

`a = a.astype('float64')`will do for numpy but I dont know for hdf5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works, but it seems to be time consuming, other solutions are appreciated.

Make a new `hdf5` file

```
>>> f2 = h5py.File('try2.hdf5')
>>> f2['try2'] = f['try'][...].astype('float64')
>>> f2['try2']
<HDF5 dataset "try2": shape (2,), type "<f8">
>>> f['try']
<HDF5 dataset "try": shape (2,), type "<i4">
```

Comment: You could load `try` into a array, use `astype` to convert, and write it back to the same file.  If you want to keep the same name use `del` to delete the original.  But the read/write to the same file probably takes the same time as to a different file.

Answer (score 1):

The [HDF5 User's Guide](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/UG/HDF5_Users_Guide-Responsive%20HTML5/HDF5_Users_Guide/Datatypes/HDF5_Datatypes.htm?rhtocid=6.2.0_2#TOC_6_3_2_Dataset_Creationbc-7) (section 6.3.2) clearly says:

> The datatype of a dataset can never be changed.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012628/4511441) question.